# Elasticsearch: store delimiters as well as tokens?

Tags: elasticsearch, sequence, tokenize

By "delimiters" I mean the token-separators: the bits of, usually, non-alphanumeric text which separates the tokens themselves.

Is this possible? I.e. store the sections of text *between* the tokens, as well as the tokens.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to perform some sequence analysis, based on sections of text which are identical except for case-variants, but also sections of text which are identical except for the delimiters between the tokens.

For that matter I also want to be able to "flatten accents", and analyse sequences which are otherwise identical on this basis: I found that ES has a way of doing that, "Ascii folding token filter".

Rather than make my own code to do this, it seems to make sense to use the info contained in an ES index - particularly if term vectors are stipulated, ES does a lot of the work needed. But this idea would be less promising if I can't in fact find a way of analysing delimiter differences.

Comment: '_source' of documents contains the unanalyzed text which is available on search request. Won't that serve your purpose?

Comment: @SahilGupta Thanks. Sort of. I'm aware of `_source`. But I will have access to the source when indexing the documents in the first place. Actually, it would need access to the precise algorithm used to get the tokens from the untokenised source or (really jumping through hoops), after ES analysing, one could compare the tokens, using term vectors, with the `_source` and thereby identify the delimiters. The fundamental problem is that I think I'm attempting to use ES for something quite alien to the thing it's designed to do... hmmm.